# How to Read the haproxy Stats Page

Tags: haproxy

For those of you using HAProxy along with the stats papge (haproxy?stats), how do I interpret this page? There is no decent explanation.

For instance: Which Session column displays the number of currently active connections to the backend? Session or Sessions Rate?

Comment: Some links to documentation re. CVS and HTML: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#stats

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Session rate is the number of new sessions per second. Under sessions, cur is the current number of sessions, max is the maximum concurrent sessions, total is the total number of sessions since haproxy was restarted.

Comment: Ok, so I'll keep my eyes on the Session columns. Can you elaborate a bit on Session rate?

Comment: Session rate is the number of new sessions per second

Comment: I don't think that a copy/paste is very helpful.

Comment: If EK's explanations don't help you, I don't know what can help you, because they look pretty clear to me.

Comment: I didn't copy/paste that to a comment, I edited the answer to make it better

Comment: @Willy of course they look clear to you, you made the app! :) With the copy/paste I meant that it's the same thing as 2 rows before it. Anyway, thanks for the info.

Comment: but cur sessions and cur session rate are not the same thing

Comment: @w00t: Late to the party, but think of it this way. You could have a bunch of  20 MS sessions with in a second, say 10 of them with *none overlapping*. If you looked at it during one of them, you would see one current session, if you look at the rate the next second, you would see 10 per second.

Comment: Is max the maximum ever seen for that server?

Comment: @hortitude Great question. I believe so because there is a LIMIT value as well. I imagine the Max would get erased with a restart or something. Not sure how it's persisted.

Comment: @hortitude (3 yrs later...) - Yes, that's max rate or max active seen by that server or backend.

Comment: @Josh Pinter stats get reset with a haproxy restart or reload.

Answer (score 20):

I think what you are confused about is the difference between *concurrency* and *arrival rate*.

Concurrency is how many things are going on at a snapshot in time. The Arrival rate is how many new things arrived during a *window* of time.

For Example:

[image]

During the snapshot there were two concurrent events. The arrival rate during that entire second is 5 events, because there were 5 events that started throughout that second. The key relationship to grasp is that a large amount of concurrent connections can come from a high arrival rate and/or long lived connections (see [Little's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law)).

Comment: Excellent explanation!!